# After installing all Swing components in Eclipse, it wil not show any option to create Swing App

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I installed all 14 components which of Swing. But I'm not able to see any Swing based option on file --> new --> other--> even though I checked whether the software is installed or not. All are perfect. I'm using Eclipse Luna.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean WindowBuilder? Swing is part of the core Java and doesn't need installing.

Comment: it works perfectly on j2ee Eclipse .. but in j2se eclipse it is not working

Comment: there is no swing specific UIs in eclipse bare installation...as mentioned only WinodwsBuilder has a Swing Designer

Comment: Ya man.. i got your point, but What i'am asking is ..i installed Window builder on eclipse but it doesn't show any windows builder option in file-->new-->other-->??..I also checked in installation details all are perfectly installed,,Even though i try to install one more time but it shows me error...the components were already installed. i'm using eclipse j2se luna

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself recently. My Eclipse became corrupt and I had to re-install it. For some reason it lost my Window Builder.

I had to go to:
Help --> Install New Software

Then I had to add the Eclipse site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

All the Swing and Window Builder stuff was under the **General Tools** section.

For Luna I suspect it might be the same, but you would need to use:
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna

[image: Eclipse Juno EE - Install New Software]